# converting plain ascii math or ascii art to mathml / latex

Tags: python, maxima, ascii-art

I'v been trying to determine the best way to convert the output from some computer algebra systems to some presentable format (mathml, latex), what would be the bestway?

i tried using the plain ascii representation, and converting to mathml, but the results are not always correct, i'v been thinking of getting the 2-d ascii art representation and changing it to mathml, are there libraries out there that can do this (im working with python)
i tried [one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/asciimathml/) and [two](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/asciitomathml/.86), but they only work with simple ascii not 2-d ascii.

```
                                      %pi
                                  3 %e      3
(%o1)                             ------- - -
                                     5      5

(%o3) 3*%e^%pi/5-3/5
```

both of the above are pretty much the same according to maxima, but converting them to 
mathml yields imperfect results, because of the '%' the order of precedence is messed up and pi ends up multiplying e rather than superscipt. Would substituting '%pi' for 'pi' be sufficient?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.hippasus.com/resources/symmath/maximatypeset.html?

Comment: @katrielalex yes, i know about maxima's ability to do that, works well with its own simple ascii inputs, but not with 2-d ascii art. moreover since im accessing it programatically (im using python)  it becomes a little clumsy (not to mention impracticall to tell when to do that) to run tex(%) after every evaluation, and this would not be a solution the moment i try to use some other CAS like axiom/singular/reduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be easy to convert that linear `%` form to asciimath, basically just remove the `%` and surround with backticks.

Using the MathJax version of Asciimath

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML">
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

`3*e^pi/5-3/5`


</body>
</html>
```

Produces

[image]

Comment: thanks, i had decided to do that as a stop gap measure, iv no idea how robust and future proof that is, but it works.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger thanks for the ping (you could have edited it:-) I'll fix, thanks.